# Panel data: create new variable with a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new variable from the following `df`. I want to create a new binary (0 or 1) variable which placed 1 in every quarter of the year if in any of their quarters the variable `entr` is equal to one, and by id.

Example from this data frame transform to:

```
id     year    quarter   fecha      entr
 1    2007          1     220       0      
 1    2007          2     221       0    
 1    2007          3     222       0 
 1    2007          4     223       0      
 1    2008          1     224       0
 1    2008          2     225       0
 1    2008          3     226       1
 1    2008          4     227       0
 1    2009          1     228       0
 1    2009          2     229       0
 1    2009          3     230       0
 1    2009          4     231       0
 2    2007          1     220       0      
 2    2007          2     221       0    
 2    2007          3     222       0 
 2    2007          4     223       0      
 2    2008          1     224       0
 2    2008          2     225       0
 2    2008          3     226       0
 2    2008          4     227       0
 2    2009          1     228       0
 2    2009          2     229       1
 2    2009          3     230       0
 2    2009          4     231       0
```

result should be look like:

```
id     year    quarter   fecha      entr   new variable
 1    2007          1     220       0           0
 1    2007          2     221       0           0
 1    2007          3     222       0           0
 1    2007          4     223       0           0
 1    2008          1     224       0           1
 1    2008          2     225       0           1
 1    2008          3     226       1           1
 1    2008          4     227       0           1
 1    2009          1     228       0           0
 1    2009          2     229       0           0
 1    2009          3     230       0           0
 1    2009          4     231       0           0
 2    2007          1     220       0           0
 2    2007          2     221       0           0
 2    2007          3     222       0           0
 2    2007          4     223       0           0
 2    2008          1     224       0           0
 2    2008          2     225       0           0
 2    2008          3     226       0           0
 2    2008          4     227       0           0
 2    2009          1     228       0           1
 2    2009          2     229       1           1
 2    2009          3     230       0           1
 2    2009          4     231       0           1
```

thank you very much and sorry for my english.

Comment: Show us code you are trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `groupby` on `id`, `year` and `transform('max')` on `entr`:

```
v = df.groupby(['id', 'year']).entr.transform('max')

v
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     0
9     0
10    0
11    0
12    0
13    0
14    0
15    0
16    0
17    0
18    0
19    0
20    1
21    1
22    1
23    1
Name: entr, dtype: int64
```

```
df['new variable'] = v
```

---

If it's possible for the maximum value to be greater than 1, you can `groupby` and call `clip` on the result:

```
df.groupby(['id', 'year']).entr.transform('max').clip(0, 1)

0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     0
9     0
10    0
11    0
12    0
13    0
14    0
15    0
16    0
17    0
18    0
19    0
20    1
21    1
22    1
23    1
Name: entr, dtype: int64
```

Which should also work for Vaishali's answer.

Comment: max is actually smarter :)

Comment: @Vaishali yeah, but similar to your solution, works for a specific case only. To generalise, you'd need the astype, or `np.clip`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
df['New_var'] = (df.groupby(['id','year']).entr.transform('sum') >= 1).astype(int)
```

Note: In the given example, just

```
df.groupby(['id','year']).entr.transform('sum')
```

works as there is only one unique 1 in each group

Comment: Ah, sorry. Was editing my answer when you posted yours. Shall I delete?

Comment: @COLDSPEED, Where is yours?

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun

```
df.groupby(['id','year']).entr.apply(lambda x : x.replace(0,max(x)))
Out[112]: 
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     0
9     0
10    0
11    0
12    0
13    0
14    0
15    0
16    0
17    0
18    0
19    0
20    1
21    1
22    1
23    1
Name: entr, dtype: int64
```